# "Call on" or "call at" or something else? Which is appropriate?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, at-on

Which one of following sentence is correct?

> You can call me **on** my cell.
>
> You can call me **at** my cell.

Or is there some other preposition? Or both are right?

Comment: You would say 'You can call me at my cell' only if you were in prison.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"On" refers to the medium:

> Call me on my cell phone.
>   Call me on the walkie-talkie.

"At" refers to the destination:

> Call me at home.  (Using my home phone number.)
>   Call me at 800-555-1212.  (The number serves as a target or destination.)

Of course, "on" and "at" can also have time-based meanings, but that doesn't seem to be what you're asking about.

Comment: Does it apply to "contact me __on__ Telegram"?

Answer (score 4):

*On* is the only acceptable preposition here; "call me *at* my cell" (or *in, to, with*, etc.) is wrong.

However, if you are specifying the number, you can use *at*: *You can reach me at (555) 555-5555*.

Also worth noting is that *You can call my cell* expresses the same meaning with fewer words. It also removes an (admittedly unlikely) potential ambiguity, since *you can call me on my cell* could mean "You can use my own cell phone to call me".

Comment: But to say "Call me at work" or "Call me at home" are perfectly valid ways to ask "Call me on my work number" and "Call me on my home number" respectively.