# Contact us "on" or "at"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, at-on

I would like to know what is the correct form and the use for inviting peoples to calling you by phone, specially in the context of written materials).

> - Contact us **on** +123 123 123
> - Contact us **at** +123 123 123

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Call on" or "call at" or something else? Which is appropriate?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51037/call-on-or-call-at-or-something-else-which-is-appropriate). Or [“Call me through/at/on this number”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55762/call-me-through-at-on-this-number)

Comment: GibboK, we now have a beta site more specifically tailored to English Language Learners. Here, on ELU, many might consider the question too basic. This might also be the reason because there are already 3 close-votes. At any rate, be aware that the ELL site exists, have a look and make yourself comfortable. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Carlo_R, I was not aware of your beta site, I am pretty in http://english.stackexchange.com thanks for your comment

Comment: Sorry, I tried calling but that seems to be the wrong number. Could you please double check for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call me at (the number) is the most widely used and correct one.